# Two questions regarding to python string methods

Tags: python, string

As I reviewing the standard library today, I found two questions that I did not notice before:

**1. What is the difference between [`str.capitalize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) and [`str.title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title)?**

> `str.capitalize()`: Return a copy of the string with its first
>   character capitalized and the rest lowercased.
>
> `str.title()`: Return a titlecased version of the string where words
>   start with an uppercase character and the remaining characters are
>   lowercase.

I don't find them to be much different? And according to the python spirit:

> "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do
>   it."

**NEVERMIND, I got it:**

```
print('hello world!'.title())        # Hello World
print('hello world!'.capitalize())   # Hello world
```

**Capitalize() will not put capital on the second word of the string contains more than one word.**

**2. [`str.swapcase()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.swapcase), in the document it mentioned:**

> Note that it is not necessarily true that s.swapcase().swapcase() ==
>   s.

Can somebody give an example? I couldn't think of any.

Comment: The description is clear, and a little experimenting would show the difference. With capitalize it is only the first letter that is capitalised, not the first letter of *each word*.

Comment: For `swapcase` they are probably talking about the inclusion of unicode, foreign, characters.

Comment: @AndyG Yes, I found that later, but what about the 2nd question?

Comment: Great guys, all clear, I will just delete this question, and I just found out that I couldn't :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`capitalize` only changes the first letter.

```
>>> s = "hello I'm here"
>>> s.capitalize()
"Hello i'm here"
```

`title` changes the letters of each word

```
>>> s.title()
"Hello I'M Here"
```

Ok that we could have known by reading the manual. Now the *really* interesting part of your question:

`swapcase` performs a `casefold` (which is slightly smarter than `lower`) which cannot be undone in some cases (german double-s/`ß` letter for instance):

```
>>> "ß".swapcase().swapcase()
'ss'
```

Comment: I don't even know how did you type that 'beta' out?

Comment: I didn't, I pasted it from a wiki page :) but Germans probably have that handy on their keyboard.

Comment: You can also hold `Alt` and press 225 on the numeric keypad.

Comment: ßßß no that doesn't work :) excellent!!!

Comment: @AndyG Doesn't seem to work for me?

Comment: Hold the left Alt key, and make sure Num Lock is on. It might also be where you are typing it...

Comment: @AndyG It worked! Did not notice that I have to input 225 from numpad.

Answer (score 1):

You could have easily found the answer to this one if you had tried little harder, but here you go.

`str.capitalize` only capitalizes the first character in a line.

`str.title` capitalizes first character of all the words in a string.

`str.swapcase`, well, swapcase of all the characters in the string.

```
>>> 'asia is A continent'.capitalize
'Asia is A continent'
>>> 'asia is A continent'.title()
'Asia Is A Continent'
>>> 'asia is A continent'.swapcase()
'ASIA IS a CONTINENT'
```